# Deriving formula for externally tangent circle to internally tangent circle

Tags: geometry, circles

[image]

($x^2+(y+1)^2=R^2$ should say $x^2+(y-1)^2=R^2$)

I am trying to derive a formula for the radius of the circle that is externally tangent to the internally tangent circles of the quarter-circle, and that is internally tangent to the quarter-circle.

Comment: this question is from a mathematics book, and it states that the radius is $\frac{4-2\sqrt{2}}{6-\sqrt{2}}R$

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mean that
$$x^2+y^2=(2R)^2\tag1$$
$$(x-\color{red}{R})^2+y^2=R^2\tag2$$
$$x^2+(y\color{red}{-R})^2=R^2\tag3$$
$$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=c^2\tag4$$

From $(1)(4)$,
$$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=2R-c\tag5$$
From $(2)(4)$,
$$\sqrt{(a-R)^2+b^2}=c+R\tag6$$
From $(3)(4)$,
$$\sqrt{a^2+(b-R)^2}=c+R\tag7$$

Since $a=b$ from $(6)(7)$, we have from $(5)(6)$,
$$a\sqrt 2=2R-c\quad\text{and}\quad \sqrt{(a-R)^2+a^2}=c+R$$
Solving this system gives
$$c=\frac{4-2\sqrt 2}{6-\sqrt 2}R.$$

Comment: Can you elaborate more?

Comment: @EitanPorat: The left hand side of $(5)$ is the distance between the centers of the circles $(1)(4)$. The same for $(6)(7)$. Does this help?

Comment: Yes, thank you for the help